# Strange behaviour on xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

I am running xdebug version: `5.4.45-1~dotdeb+7.1`

However i have some strange behaviour.

1. When my debug session takes longer then 30 seconds to a minute the application shows:

> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

2. I have weird errors like:

`_PARSE:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in xdebug://debug-eval(1) : eval()'d code:1`

It doesn't make a difference which part of the application I am debugging. I always get this error. In other words, I guess it has something to do with configuration. But I am not sure how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Change the `xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time` parameter, or add one if it does not exist in your `php.ini` eg `xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 6000`